# iOS filter certain push notifications only as badge

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I would like to send marketing push notifications that can go to the Notification Center and topics (such as breaking news) that could be very frequent in my case only as badge (I.e not persistent and only visible once the user is in the home screen but not on lock screen)

So the typical permission request for notification includes
[.alert, .sound, .badge]

But there is no method or place that I can found to process the incoming notification and tell it to ONLY show as badge. Is it even possible to do so?

This is for Swift 4and iOS min sdk 10.

Answer (score 1):

Send it as a silent notification, using the `content-available` key, and add a Notification Service Extension that updates the badge for you.

Comment: Cool! I know how to send it silent from Firebase , the content-available is just an arbitrary key that I would send in the payload (this are my options in firebase https://imgur.com/a/KdH3J)? And do you have an example for notification service extension?

Comment: `if let incr = bestAttemptContent!.badge as? Int {
 bestAttemptContent!.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: yourNewValueHere)
}`

Comment: Keep in mind for iOS you need to set the value of `content-available` to `1`.  It's not any arbitrary value, technically.